# How to generate XML field based on some condition

Tags: java, xml

If `<bby:SaleTenderType>` is eCommerce , then generate all custom fields `<Reason>102</Reason>`
`<c360:RestockingFee>0.00</c360:RestockingFee>` along with other fields

Otherwise,
Generate other fields(Except `<Reason>` and `<c360:RestockingFee>`)

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction>
<RetailTransaction>
<LineItem>
<Return ItemType="Stock">
<POSIdentity POSIDType="POSIdentity">
<POSItemID>6000000005</POSItemID>
</POSIdentity>
<ItemID>6000000005</ItemID>
<MerchandiseHierarchy Level="POSDepartment">800000039</MerchandiseHierarchy>
<Description>MODEM BLASTER V.92 USB</Description>
<UnitListPrice>50.99</UnitListPrice>
<ExtendedAmount>-50.99</ExtendedAmount>
<ExtendedDiscountAmount>-50.99</ExtendedDiscountAmount>
<Quantity>-1.00</Quantity>
<AssociateID>105251</AssociateID>
</Associate>
<Tax></Tax>
<TransactionLink ReasonCode="Return"></TransactionLink>
<ItemLink>01980</ItemLink>
<c360:SalesOrder>HD0010502948000010</c360:SalesOrder>
<Reason>101</Reason>
<c360:RestockingFee>0.00</c360:RestockingFee>
<c360:SizeCode></c360:SizeCode>
<Tender>
<TenderID>Gift Card</TenderID>
<Amount>-50.99</Amount>
<Authorization ElectronicSignature="false">
</Authorization>
<GiftCard>
<c360:CurrencyID>1</c360:CurrencyID>
<bby:SaleTenderType>eCommerce</bby:SaleTenderType>
<bby:OrderNumber>84838348938938934893</bby:OrderNumber>
</Tender>
</Return>
</LineItem>
</RetailTransaction>
</Transaction>
```

The code I have implemented is as follow..

```
if(transactions.item(a1).hasChildNodes()){
                NodeList nTranList = transactions.item(a1).getChildNodes();
                for (int b1= 0; b1< nTranList.getLength(); b1++) {
                    if(nTranList.item(b1).hasChildNodes()){
                        NodeList retailChildren = nTranList.item(b1).getChildNodes();
                        for (int j = 0; j < retailChildren.getLength(); j++)
                        {
                            if(retailChildren.item(j).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("LineItem"))
                            {
                                NodeList Lineitems = retailChildren.item(j).getChildNodes();
                                Lineitems = retailChildren.item(j).getChildNodes();
                                for (int z1 = 0; z1 < Lineitems.getLength(); z1++) {
                                    if(Lineitems.item(z1).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Return")){
                                        NodeList returnChild1 = Lineitems.item(z1).getChildNodes();
                                        for (int z2 = 0; z2 < returnChild1.getLength(); z2++) {
                                            if(returnChild1.item(z2).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Tender")){
                                                for (int z3 = 0; z3 < returnChild1.getLength(); z3++) {
                                                    if(returnChild1.item(z3).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("bby:SaleTenderType")){
                                                        String SaleTenderType = returnChild1.item(z3).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                                                        if(SaleTenderType.equalsIgnoreCase("eCommerce"))
                                                        {

                                                            Lineitems = retailChildren.item(j).getChildNodes();
                                                            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < Lineitems.getLength(); i2++) {
                                                                if(Lineitems.item(i2).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Return")){
                                                                    NodeList returnChild = Lineitems.item(i2).getChildNodes();
                                                                    for (int k = 0; k < returnChild.getLength(); k++) {
                                                                        if(returnChild.item(k).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("c360:SalesOrder")){
                                                                            String POSLOGSalesOrderNo = returnChild.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                                                                            SalesOrderNo = POSLOGSalesOrderNo.substring(2,12);
                                                                            String SalesOrderNum = POSLOGSalesOrderNo.substring(0,2);
                                                                            if(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("HD")||(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("SV"))||(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("CR"))||(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("CW")))
                                                                            {
                                                                                if ( !prevSalesOrder.equals(SalesOrderNo))
                                                                                {

                                                                                    IDocEl = outdoc.createElement("IDOC");
                                                                                    ORDERS05.appendChild(createIDocHeader_GC(POSLOGSalesOrderNo,outdoc,EMPST,IDocEl,StoreID,true,returnChild,TRANS));
                                                                                    prevSalesOrder = SalesOrderNo;
                                                                                }
                                                                                IDocEl.appendChild(createE1EDP01forReturnLineItem_GC(outdoc,returnChild,StoreID));
                                                                            }

                                                                        }
                                                                    } 
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {

                                                            Lineitems = retailChildren.item(j).getChildNodes();
                                                            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < Lineitems.getLength(); i3++) {
                                                                if(Lineitems.item(i3).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Return")){
                                                                    NodeList returnChild = Lineitems.item(i3).getChildNodes();
                                                                    for (int k = 0; k < returnChild.getLength(); k++) {
                                                                        if(returnChild.item(k).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("c360:SalesOrder")){
                                                                            String POSLOGSalesOrderNo = returnChild.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                                                                            SalesOrderNo = POSLOGSalesOrderNo.substring(2,12);
                                                                            String SalesOrderNum = POSLOGSalesOrderNo.substring(0,2);
                                                                            if(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("HD")||(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("SV"))||(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("CR"))||(SalesOrderNum.equalsIgnoreCase("CW")))
                                                                            {
                                                                                if ( !prevSalesOrder.equals(SalesOrderNo))
                                                                                {

                                                                                    IDocEl = outdoc.createElement("IDOC");
                                                                                    ORDERS05.appendChild(createIDocHeader(POSLOGSalesOrderNo,outdoc,EMPST,IDocEl,StoreID,true,returnChild));
                                                                                    prevSalesOrder = SalesOrderNo;
                                                                                }
                                                                                IDocEl.appendChild(createE1EDP01forReturnLineItem(outdoc,returnChild,StoreID));
                                                                            }

                                                                        }
                                                                    } 
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have implemented the logic for `createIDocHeader_GC(POSLOGSalesOrderNo,outdoc,EMPST,IDocEl,StoreID,true,returnChild,TRANS)` and other function definition. But in output none of the fields is being displayed. Kindly provide ur valuable inputs.

thanks..

Comment: what is that? is that even java? I do not know how to fix your problem within that mess. But if i were you, i will look for JAXB or XStream to marshall/unmarshall xml.

Comment: @bhdrkn -- Based on <bby:SaleTenderType> it should perform action. But it is not going inside the loop itself..

Comment: refer to this article on how to use breakpoints to step through your code, assuming you're on eclipse. Then once you narrow down the issue and still cannot solve it, update this question here so we can help you better. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html